# WPF: bind SelectedItem of nested ListBox to property C#

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

i have main DataTemplate ListBox which has SelectedItem = SelectedSession
and i have one more nested ListBox which has SelectedItem = AssignedExercises
if i bind the property to both selected items, i can't get the nested ListBoxe's item AssignedExercises.

Do you have some idea how to reach the nested ListBoxes SelectedItem (AssignedExercises) and bind it to property?

XAML code:

```
<ListBox Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding SessionList}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedSession}" Margin="0,0,0,20">
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Border CornerRadius="2" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2" Width="1000" Height="200" Margin="1">
            <Grid>

                <Label Content="List of exercises" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Height="30" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontWeight="Bold"></Label>

                <ListBox Height="150" Width="325" ItemsSource="{Binding AssignedExercises}" SelectedItem="{Binding AssignedExercises}">

                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Border Height="50" Width="300" BorderBrush="LightGray" BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="2" Margin="0,1,0,1">
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Margin="5,0,5,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Orientation="Horizontal">
                                        <Label Content="{Binding Name}" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </Grid>
                            </Border>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>

            </Grid>
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

The properties:

```
private TrainingSessionVM selectedSession;
private ExerciseVM selectedExercise;
public TrainingSessionVM SelectedSession
{
    get { return selectedSession; }
    set
    {
        selectedSession = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged();
    }
}
public ExerciseVM SelectedExercise
{
    get { return selectedExercise; }
    set
    {
        selectedExercise = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here i found the solution how to bind it directly through the DataContext binding:

```
SelectedItem="{Binding DataContext.SelectedExercise, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"
```

But in this case binding to the View Model should be done in this way:

```
<Grid.DataContext>
    <Binding Source="{StaticResource Locator}" Mode="OneWay" Path="TrainingSessionMain"/>
</Grid.DataContext>
```

Thx for participation.

Comment: hey! I'm sorry to see that you deleted you question, I was just trying to provide useful feedback on  improving it. I will delete my comment after you confirm reading it, this is regarding the reflection question you had (you do not have 20 rep so I cannot open a chat with you). Check out https://dotnetfiddle.net/WpbNbU and let me know if this is what you wanted!

Comment: I will delete these 2 comments after you confirm :)

Comment: @AlexC. thx for the attempt. Your code make the same as mine code. As i didn't reveal whole code. But I need to manipulate the different methods of running WinForm Application. oh = Activator.CreateInstanceFrom(executable, type);                Application.Run((Form)oh.Unwrap()); I do this in such manned and as U can see the instance of started app is separated to separate Thread, more of that it applies only to Unwrapped form. But i need running application with full control of any method, during run time.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you have a list of `Session`, each of which contains a list of `Exercise`.  Each of these could be considered a view model.

Your Main viewmodel has a `SelectedSession` to indicate which `Session` is selected.  You just need to do the same thing within the `Session` (Not the main viewmodel as in your example).  Add a `SelectedExercise` to `Session`, and bind `SelectedItem` of the inner `ListBox` to it.

You can then access the inner selected `Exercise` from the main viewmodel with `SelectedSession.SelectedExercise`.

Comment: Thx for the answer.
Both binds are in TrainingSessionMainVM.
If i add SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedSession.AssignedExercises}"
Nothing happens. Property doesn't get any value.

Comment: Right, I'm saying you should change it.  Move the `SelectedExercise` property to `TrainingSessionVM`. You will easily be able to bind to it that way, and you can still access it from the outer viewmodel.

Comment: Your binding on the inner ListBox will look like `{Binding Path=SelectedExercise}`, the property will just be on a different object.

Comment: This property is already there and it was there from the start. And i can't get access to selected item of SelectedExercise neither if it is Binded with SelectedSession.SelectedExercise or SelectedExercise.

Comment: Your example code shows that the `SelectedExercise` property is a member of your main view model, not `TrainingSessionVM`.